# How to find the relation between Area and Radius?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, area

Let $S$ be the circumcircle of a right triangle $ABC$ with $\measuredangle A = 90^{\circ}$ . Circle $X$ is a tangent to the lines $AB$ and $AC$ and internally to $S$ . Circle $Y$ is tangent to $AB$ and $AC$ and externally to $S$ . Prove that (radius of $X$) ·(radius of $Y$) is equal to four times the area of $\Delta ABC$.

My attempts:

The Circle X is touching the lines AB and AC and the Circle S, so I'm trying to calculate the relation between the radius of X and AB and AC, because half of product of AB and AC is the area of ABC, but so a relation between the radius of X and AB and AC can help. But I'm unable to find, I'm still thinking, Please help..

Comment: What is your trying?

Comment: The Circle X is touching the lines AB and AC and the Circle S, so I'm trying to calculate the relation between the radius of X and AB and AC, because half of product of AB and AC is the area of ABC, but so a relation between the radius of X and AB and AC can help. But I'm unable to find, I'm still thinking, Please help...

Comment: Next time when you post a question, please try  to include your working within the question, at the starting itself. That way, people can build on your working to formulate an answer, as well as tell you if there is anything wrong with your approach, which may be more important than the answer itself in certain instances.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

More generally,as the figure shows, for any $\triangle ABC$, let $a,b,c$ be the side length of $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Then according to the properties of the **mixtilinear circle**, we have

> $$AP=\frac{2bc}{b+c+a},~~~~AQ=\frac{2bc}{b+c-a}.$$

[image]

Now, let $A=90^{o}.$ Then $$x=AP,~~y=AQ,~~b^2+c^2=a^2,~~S_{\triangle ABC}=\frac{1}{2}bc.$$ It follows that$$xy=\frac{2bc}{b+c+a}\cdot \frac{2bc}{b+c-a}=\frac{4b^2c^2}{(b+c)^2-a^2}=\frac{4b^2c^2}{(b^2+c^2-a^2)+2bc}=2bc=4S_{\triangle ABC}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a given triangle with $\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ}$.

(I changed it. Sorry.)

Let $X$ be a center of the circle $X$, $x$ be a radius of the circle and $O$ is center of $S$.

Thus, in the standard notation $CX=x\sqrt2$, $OX=\frac{c}{2}-x$, $CO=\frac{c}{2}$ and $\measuredangle XCO=\left|45^{\circ}-\alpha\right|$.

Thus, by law of cosines we obtain:
$$OX^2=CX^2+CO^2-2CX\cdot CO\cos\measuredangle XCO$$ or
$$\left(\frac{c}{2}-x\right)^2=2x^2+\frac{c^2}{4}-cx\sqrt2\cos\left(45^{\circ}-\alpha\right)$$ or
$$x=c\left(\sqrt2\cos\left(45^{\circ}-\alpha\right)-1\right).$$
By the same way we obtain $$y=c\left(\sqrt2\cos\left(45^{\circ}-\alpha\right)+1\right),$$ where $y$ is a radius of the circle $Y$.

Id est, $$xy=c^2\left(2\cos^2\left(45^{\circ}-\alpha\right)-1\right)=c^2\cos\left(90^{\circ}-2\alpha\right)=$$
$$=c^2\sin2\alpha=2c^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=4\cdot\frac{ab}{2}=4S_{\Delta ABC}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Like @Michael, I'm also moving the right angle to $\angle C$. Also, let
$$|BC| = 2a \qquad |CA| = 2b \qquad |AB| = 2c \qquad\text{so that}\quad
|\triangle ABC| = \frac12(2a)(2b) = 2ab$$
The circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$ is the midpoint, $K$, of $\overline{AB}$; the circumradius is $c$.

[image]

Let $P$ be the center, and $r$ the radius, of the "internal" circle in question; note that $\overline{PC}$ is the diagonal of a square with sides aligned with legs of the original triangle. Let $\bigcirc P$ be tangent to $\bigcirc K$ at $T$; necessarily, $K$, $P$, $T$ are collinear. Finally, let $Q$ be such that $\triangle KPQ$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $\overline{KP}$ and with legs parallel to those of the original triangle.

With the diagram explained, we can get to the argument-proper:

$$\begin{align}
|QP|^2+|QK|^2=|KP|^2 
&\quad\to\quad |a-r|^2 + |b-r|^2 = |c-r|^2 \\
&\quad\to\quad r^2 - 2 r ( a + b - c ) = c^2-a^2-b^2 = 0 \\
&\quad\to\quad r \;\left(\; r - 2 ( a + b - c ) \;\right) = 0 \\
&\quad\to\quad r = 2 ( a + b - c )
\end{align}$$

The reader can adjust the argument appropriately and find that the radius of the question's "external" circle is $2 ( a + b + c )$.

Thus, the product of the radii is 
$$2 ( a + b - c ) \cdot 2( a + b + c ) = 4 (( a + b )^2 - c^2 ) = 4 ((a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)) = 8 a b$$
which is $4\;|\triangle ABC|$, as desired. $\square$